# Cannot execute sh file in remote server with expect

Tags: linux, bash, expect

I'm trying to use `expect` to execute some certain commands in remote server like this

- ssh_cmd.sh

```bash
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set host [lindex $argv 0]
set user [lindex $argv 1]
set passwd [lindex $argv 2]
set cmd [lindex $argv 3]

set timeout 3

spawn ssh ${user}@${host} 'bash -s' < ${cmd}

expect "*password:"

send "${passwd}\r"

expect eof
```

- pwd.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash

pwd
```

When I execute

```
ssh_cmd.sh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx root 12345 pwd.sh
```

it returns `bash: pwd.sh: No such file or directory`. However, directly executing the following command in terminal is okay and returns the path of the remote server successfully.

```
ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'bash -s' < pwd.sh
```

I wonder why and how to execute the scripts successfully.

Comment: I don't think `spawn` executes the command using a shell. So `< pwd.sh` is being sent to the remote host, not being processed locally.

Comment: @Barmar , I agree. The command is executed like `(spawn ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'bash -s')  < pwd.sh`, so that the remote server cannot find `pwd.sh`. Any suggestions that I can execute `ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'bash -s'  < pwd.sh` as a single command？

Comment: If `pwd.sh` is stored at the remote host in the correct location, you could do a `send "pwd.sh\n"`. However, this still means that your working directory must be in the PATH, which (hopefully) is not the case. Therefore I would do a `send "bash pwd.sh\r"` - after negotiating the password, or course.

Comment: Also, single quotes have no special meaning in expect (Tcl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments to `spawn` are not executed using the shell, so `< pwd.sh` is passed as literal arguments to `ssh`, and it sends them to the remote shell.

You can spawn a local `bash` to execute the command.

```
spawn bash -c "ssh ${user}@${host} 'bash -s' < ${cmd}"
```

Comment: There is a little issue, and `spawn bash -c "ssh ${user}@${host} 'bash -s' < ${cmd}"` works for me, thanks!